# Large Directory/Sub-Directory Data Transfer

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a script to go through a large directory and recursively copy the files but the destination can only accept the information 2 gigs at a time. Is there a way to break up the transfer into smaller than 2 gig parts?
I can write a simple script copying over the Main Directories but the problem is with the Destination won't accept those large transfers all at once. I was thinking of somehow having a main function to create sub-function for transferring the data in smaller segments or sessions but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Something like this but broken up into segments.

```
$SPOnlineDir = "Our sharepoint online library address"
$MainStore = @("\\server\Dir1", "\\server\Dir2", "\\server\Dir3")
function Copy-ToSPO()
{
    Foreach($StoreInst in $MainStore)
    {
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $StoreInst -Destination $SPOnlineDir -Force
    }
}
Copy-ToSPO
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use Robocopy?

Comment: @Tim Ferrill I've wrote a separate script to go through all the files and make sure their names are acceptable for the destination. For the actual copying however I am just in the planning process for how to copy them over. The sub-folders down at the base often aren't super big but there is an extensive directory structure, around a terabyte in total. I've been searching around for a solution but have found nothing as of yet.

Comment: @mjolinor We are copying from a on-sight server to Sharepoint online. We can open the library with the "open in explorer" tool but will Robocopy work across that platform?

Comment: can you perhaps show any code of what you currently have or are currently doing..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I just posted a simple copying function to the online source but the problem with it is Sharepoint online will only allow you to copy 2 gigabytes of data at a time so this wouldn't work as it.

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://stuart-moore.com/chunking-files-into-sets-of-a-certain-size-or-number-of-files-with-powershell/). You may be able to incorporate some of his code into yours to make it work.

Comment: You should be able to map the path you open in Explorer to a drive letter. `robocopy` should work in that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with a little C#:

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Source = GetSourceDirectory();
            var Destination = GetDestinationDirectory();

```
        CopyDirectory(Source, Destination);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nFinished.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static DirectoryInfo GetSourceDirectory()
    {
        var verifyPath = false;
        var pathExists = false;
        var path = "";
        while(!verifyPath)
        {
            while(!pathExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Source Directory path.");
                path = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Verifying directory exists...");

                pathExists = Directory.Exists(path);

                if (!pathExists)
                    Console.WriteLine("That path does not exist.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Directory found.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please verify the source file path (Y or N):");
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            verifyPath = GetVerification();
        }

        return new DirectoryInfo(path);
    }

    static DirectoryInfo GetDestinationDirectory()
    {
        var verifyPath = false;
        var path = "";

        while (!verifyPath)
        {
            var pathExists = false;
            var createDir = false;
            while (!pathExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Destination Directory path.");
                path = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Verifying directory exists...");

                pathExists = Directory.Exists(path);

                if (!pathExists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exist. Would you like to create it?");
                    createDir = GetVerification();
                    pathExists = createDir;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory found.");

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please verify the source file path (Y or N):");
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            verifyPath = GetVerification();

            if (verifyPath && createDir)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        return new DirectoryInfo(path);
    }

    static bool GetVerification()
    {
        char[] VerificationChoices = { 'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N' };

        var VerifiedChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        while (!VerificationChoices.Contains(VerifiedChar))
            VerifiedChar = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.Write("\n\n");

        return VerifiedChar == 'Y' || VerifiedChar == 'y';
    }

    static void CopyDirectory(DirectoryInfo DirectoryToCopy, DirectoryInfo Destination)
    {
        foreach(var SubFolder in DirectoryToCopy.GetDirectories())
        {
            var SubDestination = Destination.CreateSubdirectory(SubFolder.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Directory: " + SubDestination.FullName);
            CopyDirectory(SubFolder, SubDestination);
        }

        foreach(var File in DirectoryToCopy.GetFiles())
        {
            var FullDestinationPath = Destination.FullName + "\\" + File.Name + File.Extension;
            File.CopyTo(FullDestinationPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating File: " + FullDestinationPath);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for the input.

Comment: It goes down through and copies from the bottom up sense the sharepoint system I found out doesn't give the terabyte of storage all at once but allots the storage as you use it and thus this app get's around that by copying from the bottom file by file and creating the directory structure as well.